# What is the meaning of ^= operator in JS

Tags: javascript, operators

I am trying to figure out this operator on JS -

```
'string' ^= 'string';
```

But I can not find ant information.
Is that a comparison or assignment ?

Thanks.

Comment: If the title was't so generic I'd might find this duplicate :(

Comment: You're saying you saw `^=` being used on actual strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myVar ^= 5` is the same as `myVar = myVar ^ 5`. `^` is the bitwise `xor` operator

Let's say `myVar` was set to 2

- 5 in binary is: 101
- 2 in binary is: 010

Exclusive "or" checks the first bit of both numbers and sees 1,0 and returns 1 then sees 0,1 and returns 1 and sees 1,0 and returns 1.

Thus 111 which converted back to decimal is 7

So `5^2` is 7

```
var myVar = 2;
myVar ^= 5;
alert(myVar); // 7
```

Comment: You might consider editing the `5^2 is 7` part. I thought for a moment you meant '5 to the power of 2', which is, of course, 25 and not 7.

Comment: @11684: Math.pow does that in JavaScript. Nothing to be confused about here. alert(5^2);//7

Comment: I know, but it still was confusing. I +1'ed  after you wrapped it in `s though.

Answer (score 4):

`^` (caret) is the **Bitwise XOR** (Exclusive Or) operator.  As with more common operator combinations like `+=`, `a ^= b` is equivalent to `a = a^b`.

See the [Javascript documentation from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

`x ^= y` is [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) and shorthand for `x = x^y` - and so is technically an "assignment" to answer your question. And to be precise the single operator '^' indicates the bitwise XOR.

Comment: No, XOR is `!=`. `^` is bitwise xor.

Comment: Huh? That is 'is not'. @Bergi

Comment: @11684: Then check the truth tables. This answer is useless as long it doesn't mention that it's a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) (in an assignment shorthand)

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right. Too quick.

Comment: @bergi Hey, now I realize you were right. `!=`  indeed _is_ XOR.

Answer (score 1):

As d'alar'cop (and several others by now) already pointed out, this means something called `XOR`. I always hate to read a wikipedia explanation, so I'm going to put another explanation here:

'XOR' means 'eXclusive OR'. What is that? First an example:

```
11000110 -- random byte
10010100
--------- ^ -- XOR
01010010
```

XOR is some bitwise operation, returning two if one of two bits is 1 and the other 0. If they're both 1, it's 'and', not 'exclusive or' ('normal or' would allow two 1's).